# Difficulties loading angular2-infinite-scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, npm

I am getting 2 errors on my app:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3002/angular2-infinite-scroll

angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading       http://localhost:3002/angular2-infinite-scroll(…)

Here is the page in question:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, CanDeactivate} from 'angular2/router';
import { InfiniteScroll } from 'angular2-infinite-scroll';

@Component({
selector: 'dapps',
directives: [ InfiniteScroll ],
templateUrl: '/app/dapps/templates/dapps.component.html',
```

Down further in the component I have:

```
onScroll () {
    console.log('scrolled!!')
}
```

I installed the Infinite scroll npm package using:

```
 npm install angular2-infinite-scroll --save
```

In the template file for the component I have:

```
<div class="row" infinite-scroll
        [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
        [infiniteScrollThrottle]="500"
        (scrolled)="onScroll()">
</div>
```

edit tried:

config.js on root:

```
System.config({
//use typescript for compilation
transpiler: 'typescript',
//typescript compiler options
typescriptOptions: {
emitDecoratorMetadata: true
},
//map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
'angular2-infinite-scroll': '~/angular2-infinite-scroll'
},
//packages defines our app package
packages: {
'angular2-infinite-scroll': {
main: 'angular2-infinite-scroll.js',
defaultExtension: 'js'
}
}
```

});

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure the angular2-infinite-scroll in your systemjs config. See the config.js file in the example plunk:

https://plnkr.co/edit/DzKAiAxtAleIrT0tsqtj?p=preview

```
 map: {

   'angular2-infinite-scroll': 'node_modules/angular2-infinite-scroll'
}
```

and for the packages object add:

```
'angular2-infinite-scroll': {
  main: 'angular2-infinite-scroll.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

Comment: This answer does not solve the question. The OP states that they have installed the library through NPM, so the actual entry in the system-js.config file should be something like `map: { 'angular2-infinite-scroll': '~/angular2-infinite-scroll' }`

Comment: My mistake. Copied directly from the config in the plunk - but as you say just rename to local reference (which is probably 'node_modules/angular2-infinite-scroll')

Comment: Thanks for helping but I am unsure as to where to find this systemjs file, I can just see a systemjs folder? Is it on the same level as the package.json file? Thanks! - Edit  I installed via npm can I just rename something?

Comment: In the project root I have created the config.js file and inside I have the system.config with the map and package object. Still getting the same issue however. The 404 error is at node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js

Comment: If you look at the plunk you can see that the config.js is referenced in the index.html - you should have the same in your index.html (or systemjs.config.js - which is used as name for this file in other angular examples). Also see the config.js in the plunk for the full file contents. I didn't mean that you should add the config.js file btw, just modify your existing (you should check what name it has in your project).