# Firebase 404 not found

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, npm

I am running an Angular2 application,  I have installed Firebase through npm and I import it into my app.component.ts.

No errors come up in my text-editor, as it can find Firebase. I have checked my package.json and it is installed correctly.

Yet when I run my application, it crashes and the browser prints out an error message to the console saying:

```
localhost/:24 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
http://localhost:3000/firebase(…)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate :)

Comment: why are you calling firebase using localhost?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/39097251/3476801

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the error, the link Subtain provided (which matches the error message) is the best best. If you want more help, share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need call firebase using firebase link: [image]

And add what you want next.

```
https://petprject.firebaseio.com/cars
```

for example.

Comment: Thats just a call to the database,  I am trying to import the firebase library into angular2 so I can use firebase classes/

Comment: oh for christs sake. the db name is a url, wtf.  thank you !!! I would have never figured that out.